# sql server data insertion, first row closing balance should be next row opening balance

Tags: sql-server

I am facing the problem while inserting data this way.

[image]

How to insert data this way using stored procedure.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].tbl_Transaction                
        (                
             [FK_GameID] ,            
             [SpotID] ,            
             TransactionReason ,            
             TransactionType ,            
             TransactionAmount
             --PrevAmountBalance,
            -- CurrentBalance
        )                
       SELECT tblTransaction.Row.value('@FK_GameID','BIGINT'),            
       tblTransaction.Row.value('@SpotID','SMALLINT'),            
       tblTransaction.Row.value('@TransactionReason','SMALLINT'),            
       tblTransaction.Row.value('@TransactionType','Varchar(50)'),            
       tblTransaction.Row.value('@TransactionAmount','MONEY')
       --@OpeningBalance,
       -- (@OpeningBalance-tblTransaction.Row.value('@TransactionAmount','MONEY'))
       FROM @TransactionTable.nodes('/row') AS tblTransaction(Row)
```

Comment: I think you need to clarify the question..

Comment: thank you , How can it be that first row closing balance should be inserted as next row opening balance.

Comment: You should just keep a record of the transaction amount. You can very easily aggregate the data to get opening and closing balances for any time period. Relational databases and SQL **are not** the same as a spreadsheet.

Comment: @Mohan, Tag it with [tag:sql-server], not [tag:sql] and [tag:server]

Comment: In addition to Yuck's comment, it also looks highly suspicious to have a table that can, apparently, only track one account - why isn't there some kind of ID that links these 3 rows together, but allows other "row 1"s to exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table #balances(
id int not null identity(1,1),
opening_balance int, 
closing_balance int, 
t_type varchar(50))
```

to start the table (if you don't have this you will have to deal with NULLs)

```
insert into #balances values (100 , 100 , 'start')
```

query:

```
insert into #balances values(
(select top 1 closing_balance from #balances order by id desc),
300, --new value
'credit')
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. but I'm inserting data using xml and attaching the code.